# String handling in DLL/Exe in Delphi

Tags: delphi, dll

I've inherited an application that consists of an EXE and a DLL, both use ShareMem as the first unit. The application expects to pass a string (of type string, not PChar/PWideChar)

The application has a unit that defines a "string" variable, which is included in both the EXE and the DLL. The expectation is that the DLL will set the variable (based on some data passed to the DLL) and later use it...

I've tried to provide a minimal complete example application that demonstrates the behaviour below...

The variable defined in a shared unit

```
unit SharedValues;

interface

var
  SomeVariable: string;

implementation

end.
```

The exe...
The dpr...
    program ExeProject;

```
uses
  ShareMem,
  Vcl.Forms,
  Main in 'src\Main.pas' {Form1},
  SharedValues in '..\Shared\SharedValues.pas';
```

The main form...

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  lLibraryName = 'DllProject.dll';
var
  lDllHandle: THandle;
  lLength: Integer;

  lCreatorFunc: function: Integer; stdcall;
begin
  SharedValues.SomeVariable := 'Shared variable set in EXE';

  lDllHandle := LoadLibrary(PChar(lLibraryName));
  if (lDllHandle <> 0) then
  begin
    lCreatorFunc := GetProcAddress(lDllHandle, 'LoadDll');
    if Assigned(lCreatorFunc) then
    begin
      OutputDebugString(PChar(Format('In Exe (before dll): Shared Variable: %s (%d) 0x%p', [SharedValues.SomeVariable, Length(SharedValues.SomeVariable), @SharedValues.SomeVariable])));

      lLength := lCreatorFunc;

      OutputDebugString(PChar(Format('Length returned from DLL: %d', [lLength])));

      OutputDebugString(PChar(Format('In Exe (after dll): Shared Variable: %s (%d) 0x%p', [SharedValues.SomeVariable, Length(SharedValues.SomeVariable), @SharedValues.SomeVariable])));
    end;
  end else begin
    ShowMessage(SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
  end;
end;
```

The DLL

```
library DllProject;

uses
  ShareMem,
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes,
  WinApi.Windows,
  SharedValues in '..\Shared\SharedValues.pas';

{$R *.res}

function LoadDll: Integer; stdcall;
begin
  OutputDebugString(PChar('DLL Before: ' + SharedValues.SomeVariable));

  SharedValues.SomeVariable := 'short';

  OutputDebugString(PChar('DLL After: ' + SharedValues.SomeVariable));

  Result := Length(SharedValues.SomeVariable);
end;

exports
  LoadDll;

begin
end.
```

Output of the above...

```
Exe Before: Shared variable set in EXE 
DLL Before:  
DLL After: short 
Exe After: Shared variable set in EXE Length: 5
```

So what's going on here? As I debug and look at the memory location of the variable (using Addr and/or "@") it looks like the variable is the same address in the exe and the dll, but I think I've got a copy of the variable in the EXE and a copy in the DLL... however under the debugger I see after setting "SharedValues.SomeVariable" the variable is unchanged (ie, seems to be the value from the exe, not from what is set in the DLL).

[image]

Can someone clear the air a little here/point me in the right direction?

Comment: Of course they are distinct variables, Sharemem can be used to pass strings to/from exe/dll. Just output the address in LoadDll.

Comment: Did you see the picture where the variable doesnt appear to be set? In the actual application the variable appears to be an empty string and later fails because the string is empty, despite being set in the DLL.

Comment: Debugger might be confused by the similarly named variables. Debug output the address, content etc..

Comment: Already done that - I get the same address in both cases.

Comment: It's not possible. Repeat the test.

Comment: What you share when you use sharemem is the memory manager, the variable (pointer) in the dll still lives in the memory image of the module which starts from the loading address, which you can see pressing ctrl+alt+M.